# Infer generic constraints with explicitly specified generic parameters

Tags: generics, f#, type-inference

Consider this code:

```
let f<'a when 'a:comparison> (x: 'a) = ()
let g x = f x
let h<'b> (x: 'b) = f x
```

The function `f` has a generic parameter constrained with comparison.
In function `g`, I just use `f` and let the compiler infer generic parameters, which it correctly does, resulting in `g: 'a -> unit when 'a : comparison`.

However, if I need to specify generic parameters explicitly, as in function `h`, the compiler fails to infer constraints for some reason, resulting in a red squiggly under `x`, saying "*A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when 'b : comparison'.*"

This is especially annoying with functions that don't have non-generic parameters, i.e. `let f<'a> = ()`, or whose non-generic parameters don't mention generic types, i.e. `let f<'a> () = ()`, because I end up having to specify the constraints every single time I use such functions in another generic function:

```
let f<'a when 'a:comparison> () = ()
let g<'a> () = f<'a> () // Error: A type parameter is missing a constraint 
let h () = f<'a> () // h gets inferred as unit -> unit, losing generic parameter
let k<'a when 'a:comparison> () = f<'a> () // The only working way
```

Is there a trick to have the compiler infer the constraints for me?

Comment: I don't think there is a trick you could use - ideally, you would not need to make the type parameters of functions explicit because the compiler should be able to figure them out - or do you have some reason for requiring them?

Comment: The compiler can only figure out types that are used either in parameters or in result. I need a function that acts on types, not on values. This is used in conjunction with static constraints, similar to how generic zero works.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `g` from your second set of functions and `h` generates the warning:

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the
>   type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type
>   'System.IComparable'.

So, it seems the error in `g` is preventing a full type-check of `h`.

Comment: Even if I remove `g`, `h` will still not be generic. The goal is to later use it like `let x = h<string> ()`.

Comment: No, `h` still won't be generic, but removing `g` reveals the true behavior. I was just pointing out that the type parameter isn't being completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only annotate the type parameters after the *arguments* and/or the *return type*, and not the *function name*, the type inference seems to work.

To follow from your first example:

```
let f<'a when 'a:comparison> (x: 'a) = ()

let i (x: 'b) = f x 
// val i : x:'b -> unit when 'b : comparison
```

It also works if the arguments have a generic type and/or an additional type constraint themselves:

```
let j (x: 'c list) = f x.Head
// val j : x:'c list -> unit when 'c : comparison

let k (x: 'd when 'd:unmanaged) = f x
// val k : x:'d -> unit when 'd : unmanaged and 'd : comparison
```

You should be able to code in this way just fine, since specifying the type parameter in the function name is unnecessary.

Even if you use a constrained type more than once, you only need to describe it the first time:

```
let l (x: 'e when 'e:unmanaged) (y : 'e) = f x
// val l : x:'e -> y:'e -> unit when 'e : unmanaged and 'e : comparison
```

All the same tricks works with the return type:

```
let f'<'a when 'a:comparison> () = (new obj ()) :?> 'a

let g' () : 'b when 'b : unmanaged = f' ()
// val g' : unit -> 'b when 'b : unmanaged and 'b : comparison
```

So the only pain point left is a generic function that has neither a generic input parameter nor a generic return type.

Comment: This doesn't help with functions that don't have parameters, see second half of the question.